# How can I average multiple arrays assigned to one variable?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to interpret a large data set into multiple smaller 128 by 128 arrays to later average together into one singular array of the same size.

I've been able to create one very long array with a shape of (-1,128), and I have been able to segment this into smaller 128 by 128 parts.

```
data = rawdata.reshape((-1, 128))
for x in range(5):
    data_avg = data[0 + 128 * x:128 + 128 * x, :]
    print(data_avg) #returns 5 128 by 128 arrays assigned to "data_avg"
```

The problem is I don't know how to take this data and average it all together, as it is all assigned to the same variable. I also don't really want the program to create a new variable for each array, as in the final product the program will be reading hundreds of arrays at a time.

Update: I have now been able to store the data in a list as multiple arrays, but I have still not found a way to average the arrays themselves. Attempting to do so with np.mean(data_list) results in one singular integer, not a full array.

Comment: I have successfully stored the arrays into a list, but I still cannot average the individual arrays together, running an average only results in one integer

Comment: See my answer for a simple way of doing this. Note that in my answer, the 100 is known by me, but can be calculated by dividing each axis in the original array by 128 and then multiplying the results. So in my example, z = arr.size / 128^2 and mean = arr.reshape((128, 128, z)).mean(axis = 2). My answer requires that the size your data array be divisible by 128^2 though.

Comment: Did you read about the `axis` parameter of `np.mean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = np.random.normal(size = (1280, 1280))
mean = arr.reshape((128, 128, 100)).mean(axis = 2)
```

arr is some array of shape (x*128, y*128) and in one line is reshaped into xy number of 128x128 arrays and the mean taken along the xy axis.